# how to get binance-python testnet updating balance?

Tags: python, python-3.x, binance

I am trying to get acquainted to **python-binance** (0.7.5) (**on Python 3.7.6**) and struggling to understand why my command doesn't seem to do anything. I am connecting to **testnet**. I can get account details, ticker prices, calculate step, get balances etc - all of which works very well.

But when I try to run :

```
client.order_market_sell(symbol='LTCBTC', quantity=quantity)
```

with max amount I have available on testnet for LTC, **nothing happens**. The balance on my testnet does not change at all. I get **no error messages** and if I pass the command to a variable, then it provides me with the order details as such :

> {'symbol': 'LTCBTC', 'orderId': 73, 'orderListId': -1,
> 'clientOrderId': 'QPlrA9KN1Dj1mAnmB8SDtc', 'transactTime':
> 1597905287816, 'price': '0.00000000', 'origQty': '487.42796000',
> 'executedQty': '0.00000000', 'cummulativeQuoteQty': '0.00000000',
> 'status': 'EXPIRED', 'timeInForce': 'GTC', 'type': 'MARKET', 'side':
> 'SELL', 'fills': []}

I have updated python-binance. I have tried changing the quantity to a small number, like 5, 1 or 0.5. I have also tried ETH, BNB, TRX, XRP but all do the same. I tried using the limit command but that just puts the funds into locked. How will I get this to actually work correctly and then affect the balance accordingly ?

I am also struggling to get the fees from the prices which works fine on binance non-testnet.

> File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\binance\client.py", line 2086,
> in get_trade_fee
> if not res['success']:
>
> KeyError: 'success'

With that error I tried absolutely nothing, other than taking a hard-coded fee such as 0.001 or 0.01. I could also find no post anywhere with that specific error.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, the Testnet isn't a mirror of the actual network of cryptocurrencies but it's own network where the prices are set against the real networks. This means to make a trade, there needs to be someone/something else to trade with.

Maybe you already found [this post](https://dev.binance.vision/t/i-cant-do-market-order-always-status-expired/828), but it essentially explains that the error is because there's no liquidity for that symbol. I found that BNBUSDT and BTCUSDT were working.

This isn't ideal for me either, so I'll be trying to find another way to Algo paper trade.